# Creating two modal buttons that open different popup windows

Tags: javascript, popup

Essentially I have two links.  I would like link 1 to open up a popup (let's say Popup 1), and link 2 to open up a separate popup (Popup 2).  As it is now, both open only Popup 2.  What exactly in this code needs to be changed?

The code is visible here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mattwalker1092/xxgt4tm5/
Or, alternatively, below:

```css
body {
 background: #1f1f2e; }
 
ppopup {
    color: #000000;
 font-family: "cambria";
 font-size: 22px } 

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: scroll; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */ }

.modal-content {
    background-color: #dbd9d7;
 text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
 height: 70%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 overflow-y: scroll; }
 
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold; }
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer; }

button {
    background:none!important;
    border:none; 
    padding:0!important;
  
 color: #cc9966;
 font-family: "Century Gothic";
 font-size: 16px;
 text-decoration: none;}
 
.txt:hover {
    text-decoration: underline; }
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<center><button id="myBtnONE"><span class="txt" style="cursor:pointer">Link 1</span></button></center>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalONE" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p><ppopup>
 This is my FIRST TEST
 </ppopup></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModalONE');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnONE");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block"; }
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none"; }
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none"; } }
</script>


<center><button id="myBtnTWO"><span class="txt" style="cursor:pointer">Link 2</span></button></center>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalTWO" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p><ppopup>
  This is a SECOND TEST
 </ppopup></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModalTWO');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtnTWO");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block"; }
span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none"; }
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none"; } }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://jsfiddle.net/nf6bcpdu/. Just use some `onclick` events to bind what you want to happen.

```
<center><button id="myBtnONE"><span class="txt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="OpenModalOne();">Link 1</span></button></center>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalONE" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close"  onclick="CloseModalOne();">&times;</span>
    <p><ppopup>
    This is my FIRST TEST
    </ppopup></p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

function OpenModalOne() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModalONE');
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function OpenModalTwo() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModalTWO');
    modal.style.display = "block";
}

function CloseModalOne() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModalONE');
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

function CloseModalTwo() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModalTWO');
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>script>

<center><button id="myBtnTWO"><span class="txt" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="OpenModalTwo();">Link 2</span></button></center>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModalTWO" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close" onclick="CloseModalTwo();">&times;</span>
    <p><ppopup>
        This is a SECOND TEST
    </ppopup></p>
  </div>
</div>
```